# Change Terminal Font Size with C++

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, ncurses

I'm doing a small project for fun in C++ (in Ubuntu 11.04) and the program is text-based (all in the Gnome terminal). I'm using the ncurses library to change the font color, but I also want to print different sized text to the terminal, and can't figure out how to do that with ncurses. Is there a way to do this (perhaps with ncurses, or with a different library)? Ideally, I'd want it to be terminal-independent,, but if it's a solution that only works in Gnome, or only works in Ubuntu, or some other restriction like that then that's better than nothing!

Thanks for your help as always.

---

I've tried the suggestion from Keith Thompson but couldn't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
cout << "\x1b]50;" << "10x20" << "\a" << flush;
cout << "test";
```

It just shows up as the same font size specified in the terminal preferences. I'm using: GNOME Terminal 2.32.1 if that helps!

Comment: You had me at the word 'fun' ..and then you went and spoilt it with C++ :( But actually even though it's an old question it's a curious one. C (and I am pretty sure the same applies to C++) itself doesn't really have a concept of fonts and that's only part of the story (you already mentioned to it - the terminal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least for `xterm`, you can change the current font by printing an escape sequence.  The syntax is `ESCAPE ] 50 ; FONTNAME BEL`.

Here's (an abbreviated version of) a script I use for this; I call it `xfont` (the real one has more error checking):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "\e]50;@ARGV\a";
```

I don't know which other terminal emulators recognize this sequence.  In particular, I find that it doesn't work under `screen`, even if the `screen` session is in an `xterm` window.

Note that you have to specify the *name* of the font (`"10x20"`, `"9x15"`), not its size.

EDIT: I should pay more attention to tags.  In C++, it would be something like:

```
std::cout << "\x1b]50;" << font_name << "\a" << std::flush;
```

UPDATE: With `xterm`, this won't work if you're using TrueType fonts. Also, Dúthomhas suggests in a comment:

> I know this is old, but all terminfo strings should be printed using
>   `putp()` [or `tputs()`], even in C++.
>
> `putp( (std::string{ "\33]50;" } + font_name + "\a").c_str() );`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Your answer seemed promising, but I can't get it to work :/. Perhaps I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Perhaps Gnome terminal doesn't recognize the same escape sequence.  Try launching an xterm window (`xterm &`) and try it from there.  Run `xlsfonts` for a list of available fonts (there are several thousand on my system).  Or `xlsfonts | egrep '^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$'` for a list of WIDTHxHEIGHT font names (I have 14 of those).  If it works in xterm but not in Gnome terminal, there be a Gnome-specific solution.  (Or it may not be possible; if Gnome implemented this functionality, I'd expect it to use the same syntax as `xterm`.)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in xterm either :/. I even tried your perl example: `print "\e]50;10x20\a"; print "test";` and the font was the same size in gnome and xterm. Maybe this is something that has changed recently. What OS/terminal do you run your xfont system on?

Comment: @navr91: I use this on Ubuntu and Cygwin, and I've used it on other systems in the past.  Hmm.  Control-right-click in an xterm window, and see whether "`Allow font ops`" is enabled.  The corresponding X resource name is `allowFontOps`.

Comment: @navr91: To be clear, if the method I described works, it will change the font size for the entire window, and probably change the size of the window to accommodate.  If you're trying to display text of different font sizes simultaneously in the same window, a typical terminal emulator won't let you do that.

Comment: Ahh, allow font ops wasn't enabled. And I understand that it'll change the font of the entire window, that's fine with me. That did the trick, thanks Keith.

Comment: I know this is old, but all terminfo strings should be printed using putp() [or tputs()], even in C++. `putp( (std::string{ "\33]50;" } + font_name + "\a").c_str() );`

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to use bold font. Terminal emulates real text-based terminal so it doesn't support different fonts at once.

Answer (score 0):

ncurses does not change *font sizes*, but does manipulate *styles* within a font using the video attributes (bold, italic).  Some terminals have a documented way to change their font size, which affects the whole window (making it "invisible" to ncurses).

As noted, xterm has a feature for setting a font which is documented in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-5-0.1019), in the [*Operating System Commands*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands) section:

```
        Ps = 5 0  ⇒  Set Font to Pt.  These controls may be disabled
      using the allowFontOps resource.  If Pt begins with a "#",
      index in the font menu, relative (if the next character is a
      plus or minus sign) or absolute.  A number is expected but not
      required after the sign (the default is the current entry for
      relative, zero for absolute indexing).

      The same rule (plus or minus sign, optional number) is used
      when querying the font.  The remainder of Pt is ignored.

      A font can be specified after a "#" index expression, by
      adding a space and then the font specifier.

      If the TrueType Fonts menu entry is set (the renderFont
      resource), then this control sets/queries the faceName
      resource.
```

The manual page documents [*faceName*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName) as the font-family name.  While one could try adding the *pixelsize* property to that, it might not work.  But changing the *faceName* works (assuming that you have selected TrueType fonts), e.g., using this script on my current machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
setfont() {
read -p "$1:"
printf '\033]50;%s\007' "$1"
read -p "done!"
}
setfont "Bitstream Charter"
setfont "URW Gothic L"
```

I got those names using `fc-list`.
A similar script would work for bitmap fonts, using the names found with `xlsfonts`.  For bitmap fonts, there are *font aliases* such as `9x15`, `10x20`, `12x24`, but those are only defined for a few combinations of perhaps a thousand results from `xlsfonts`.  For that, read the [*X Logical Font Description Conventions*](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html) documentation.  Those useful font aliases, by the way, are not systematically documented anywhere.

That only changes the appearance of the characters and might not change the **size**.  But reading the documentation, it is possible (using a feature adapted from *rxvt*) to use a number to step through the settings on the font menu.  This script works for me, changing the font up one, twice, down two (back to the default), up four (to the end of the settings), and back:

```
#!/bin/bash
changesize() {
read -p "$1:"
printf '\033]50;#%s\007' "$1"
read -p "done!"
}
changesize +1
changesize +1
changesize -2
changesize +4
changesize -4
```

Because this uses a control sequence that is not from the terminal database, a **`cout`** or **`printf`** in your program is suitable.  You should use **`putp`** for strings which come from the terminal database because they can contain padding information which is interpreted by [**`putp`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions) (and which would not be useful when printed directly to the terminal).  Conversely, some random control sequence **could** look like something that could confuse **`putp`**.

Padding is documented in [`terminfo(5)`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Types-of-Capabilities).