# Is there any way to print different fonts in the terminal using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a package that allows you to format the text printed in the terminal. Is there anyway I can print a different font in the terminal.

Example :

```
text = module.font("Hello World", "Times New Roman")
print(text)
```

Output : `>>> Hello World (in the Times New Roman font)`

How could I implement different fonts to be printed in the terminal.

Comment: Most (I'd say _all_, but who knows) terminals don't support more than one font at the same time.

Comment: This is terminal dependent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703368/c-how-to-change-font-size-in-ncurses/33676928

Comment: How do I do it with Python though?